# Handle case fail and success when implement copy to clipboard

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying implement **copy to clipboard** feature into my project.

Here is my code about this function:

```
export const copyToClipboard = str => {
  const el = document.createElement('textarea');
  el.value = str;
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  el.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(el);
  // I need know when this function executed fail to display notify for the end user.
  // Like: isSuccess ? toast.success("Copy success") : toast.error("Copy fail")
};
```

So, How I can handle fail or success when this function executed ?
Any body have any idea for this case ?

Answer (score 1):

Prefer to use **Clipboard API** !
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard#Using_the_Clipboard_API

```
export const copyToClipboard = str =>
{
  navigator.clipboard
    .writeText( str )
    .then(_=>{ /* clipboard successfully set */ }
         ,_=>{ /* clipboard write failed */     }
    );
}
```

Comment: Just keep in mind the API is not supported by IE or Edge, among some others:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API

Comment: JavaScript modules doesn't exist either on IE too